# Extract MMS Ref with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Okay I have:

`<ASX version = "3.0">
<Entry>
    <Ref href = "mms://173.239.17.41/FGM-Streams/baker/000803-Heidi_Baker-Signs_&_Wonders-3.wmv" />
</Entry>
</ASX>`

And as a file content string, and I want to extract just the line of the ref href = "...." so I can get the MMS URL.

How do I `preg_match()` that?

Comment: shudder, i actually watched the first few seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to match `mms`-links only, the regex you need perhaps should mention it:

```
if (preg_match('#(mms:[^"]*)#', $test_string, $matches) ) { ... }
```

*(actually, it may be better to use `mms:[^"'\s]*` instead, as it will work even if quotations marks are single - or omitted completely)*

Otherwise, just capture the `href` part:

```
if (preg_match('#href\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"#', $test_string, $matches) ) { ... }
```

The approach (in general) is simple: you capture everything, starting from a 'opening delimiter' that is not a closing delimiter (which is `"` in your case).